# Protege - Specifying primary key and foregin key for RDF file

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, protege

Using protege, I am creating RDF file. Now I want to know to how to specify an slot is an primary and foreign keys to the given classes? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

For a primary key you have to have to create a property that is `owl:InverseFunctionalProperty`. For instance, imagine that the class `Person` has a primary key for the social security number (SSN) then in our ontology we would have:

```
:hasSSN  rdf:type  owl:InverseFunctionalProperty .
```

Logically, this means that if two elements A and B have the value for the property `:hasSSN` then A and B are the same individual.

The closest thing to foreign keys are `ranges`, so you could say that the range of the predicate `:hasSSN` is the class `:SSN`:

```
:hasSSN  rdfs:range :SSN .
```

Range works both for classes and data ranges.

In protege, you can mark a predicate as `owl:InverseFunctionalProperty` going to the Object Properties panel, there is a checkbox for it. Right next to it you can add ranges and domains.

[image]

Comment: tanx for ur answer. But I dnt find above option when I am trying to create RDF file.

Comment: @Winbros have you selected the object properties panel ? by the way this screenshot is from Protege version 4.1 - maybe you have a different version.

Comment: I am using 3.4 version. Let me check once again and get back to you